# UnicodeError Python 3 & Requests

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, shopify

I've used requests before with Python 2.7 and I never had this issue. Now I'm coding in Python 3 and it won't even get connect to the server.

I keep getting the error: `UnicodeError: label empty or too long`

Simplified code for illustration purpose:

```
shop_url = "https://APIKEY:CODE@SHOP.ECOMMERCE.com/admin/"

def get_products():
    url = shop_url + "products.json"
    r = requests.get(url=url, params={"limit": "250"})
    response = r.json()
    print(response)
```

I've read it has to do with the IDNA coding of the url before it connects to the server.

Is there anyone who knows how to solve this problem?

EDIT:
I've found the solution, instead of passing the APIKEY & CODE in the URL. I can pass it in the header as HTTPBasicAuth. Than the url changes to `"http://SHOP.ECOMMERCE.com/admin/"` and IDNA no longer gives any issues.

Comment: What version of requests are you using?

Comment: python 3.6 & requests 2.12.4

Comment: Edit: Just updated to 2.13.0, unfortunately does not solve the problem.

Comment: **For anyone stumbling here**. I am not sure why Requests lib enforces this so strict. I looked for a simple workaround in the source, no luck.  So, here is the headers to send (as they were not mentioned explicitly above).  

```headers = { 'Authorization': SHOPIFY_KEY, 'X-Shopify-Access-Token': SHOPIFY_PASSWORD,}```

Above worked for me.  

The Shopify documentation currently, and as usual, has errors and typos on the topic of headers and everything.  #jobSecurity.  Good platform, not helpful support.

Answer (score 1):

According to the report (*still* open!) at [Python tracker issue 32958](https://bugs.python.org/issue32958), the issue here is that `requests` in Python 3 now passes URLs to `idna.py` (a change from Python 2).

`idna.py` attempts to sanity-check hostnames before passing them to `socket.gethostbyname()`. It does this by first checking whether the first component (or possibly each component) of the name is less than 64 characters in length.

(Each of a hostname's dot-separated components — referred to as "labels" in [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-2.3.1) — has a length restriction. So, the *idea* behind the check is a sound one, as hostname components longer than 64 characters are invalid according to standards.):

> The labels must follow the rules for ARPANET host names.  They must
> start with a letter, end with a letter or digit, and have as interior
> characters only letters, digits, and hyphen.  There are also some
> restrictions on the length.  Labels must be 63 characters or less.

Unfortunately, when `idna.py` checks the hostname length, it includes ***everything*** from the protocol separators up to the first `.` character — including any basic-auth parameters specified in the URL.

The workaround is, as you already found, to supply the auth parameters in the request headers.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, instead of passing the APIKEY & CODE in the URL. I can pass it in the header as HTTPBasicAuth. Than the url changes to "http://SHOP.ECOMMERCE.com/admin/" and IDNA no longer gives any issues.