# Long URL (including a key) causes unicode idna codec decoding error whilst using RedisChannelLayer in Django Channels

Tags: sockets, unicode, redis, django-channels

I've encountered a problem deploying Django Channels on Heroku, whilst using a RedisChannelLayer.

I get a `UnicodeError: encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label empty or too long)` during connection (full traceback below).

That seems to be a problem related to one of the labels in the host address being too long [as shown in this python issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue32958).

I printed some information out of my consumer, and also wrapped python's `socket.getaddrinfo` module to display host and connection information.

[This related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41831124/unicodeerror-python-3-requests) has has the same problem connecting to shopify, not a redis instance, where they got around it by placing credentials into the request header. But I don't have control over `channels_redis` or `asyncio`.

Any clues?

#### Properties of the Django Channels Consumer:

**.groups** `[]`

**.channel_layer** `RedisChannelLayer(hosts=[{'address': ('h:alongkeycomprisingof65charsintotalxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@ec2-18-202-152-61.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com', '9759')}])`

**.channel_name** `specific.OSfTzyqY!pdvgHnaCxWiv`

**.room_name** `8e3d3083-8bb1-4d85-89d3-4496d9b9e946`

**.room_group_name** `twined_8e3d3083-8bb1-4d85-89d3-4496d9b9e946`

#### Full Traceback:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/sessions.py", line 183, in __call__
 return await self.inner(receive, self.send)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/middleware.py", line 41, in coroutine_call
 await inner_instance(receive, send)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/consumer.py", line 59, in __call__
 [receive, self.channel_receive], self.dispatch
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/utils.py", line 51, in await_many_dispatch
 await dispatch(result)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/consumer.py", line 73, in dispatch
 await handler(message)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/generic/websocket.py", line 175, in websocket_connect
 await self.connect()
 File "/app/backend/pink/consumers.py", line 24, in connect
 await self.channel_layer.group_add(self.room_group_name, self.channel_name)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 589, in group_add
 async with self.connection(self.consistent_hash(group)) as connection:
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 835, in __aenter__
 self.conn = await self.pool.pop()
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 73, in pop
 conns.append(await aioredis.create_redis(**self.host, loop=loop))
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aioredis/commands/__init__.py", line 175, in create_redis
 loop=loop)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aioredis/connection.py", line 113, in create_connection
 timeout)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py", line 339, in wait_for
 return (yield from fut)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aioredis/stream.py", line 24, in open_connection
 lambda: protocol, host, port, **kwds)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 750, in create_connection
 infos = f1.result()
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 56, in run
 result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
 File "./backend/amy/asgi.py", line 69, in mygetaddrinfo
 for res in socket._socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
 UnicodeError: encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label empty or too long)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to work around by establishing my `RedisChannelLayer` using a dict of arguments to `create_connection` (as mentioned [here](https://pypi.org/project/channels-redis/), instead of providing a really long host name.

By manually parsing the password out of the REDIS_URL variable that heroku provides me, and rebuilding a `host` uri without it, I can add that password as a separate field to the `create_connection` dict, keeping the host string length below 64 characters.

I do this in my `settings.py` file which now looks like:

```
def parse_redis_url(url):
    """ parses a redis url into component parts, stripping password from the host.
    Long keys in the url result in parsing errors, since labels within a hostname cannot exceed 64 characters under
    idna rules.
    In that event, we remove the key/password so that it can be passed separately to the RedisChannelLayer.
    Heroku REDIS_URL does not include the DB number, so we allow for a default value of '0'
    """
    parsed = urlparse(url)
    parts = parsed.netloc.split(':')
    host = ':'.join(parts[0:-1])
    port = parts[-1]
    path = parsed.path.split('/')[1:]
    db = int(path[0]) if len(path) >= 1 else 0

    user, password = (None, None)
    if '@' in host:
        creds, host = host.split('@')
        user, password = creds.split(':')
        host = f'{user}@{host}'

    return host, port, user, password, db

REDIS_URL = env('REDIS_URL', default='redis://localhost:6379')
REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT, REDIS_USER, REDIS_PASSWORD, REDIS_DB = parse_redis_url(REDIS_URL)

# DJANGO CHANNELS
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [{
                'address': f'redis://{REDIS_HOST}:{REDIS_PORT}',
                'db': REDIS_DB,
                'password': REDIS_PASSWORD,
            }],
        },
    },
}
```